# Qt and Crypto++ linker errors

Tags: c++, qt, linker, crypto++

I'm getting a bunch of LNK2001 and LNK2019 errors with Qt 5.4 and Crypto++. Tried both static and dynamic linking. Libs are in the project folder and .pro file has something like:

```
win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/ -lcryptlib

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/include

DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/include

win32:!win32-g++: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/cryptlib.lib

else:win32-g++: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/libcryptlib.a
```

As soon as I reference something from cryptopp header files I get 15+ linker errors. Also, lib was built with the same MSVC2013 compiler I'm using for Qt.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Yeah, sorry for not including the errors.

```
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl CryptoPP::Algorithm::Algorithm(bool)" (??0Algorithm@CryptoPP@@QEAA@_N@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl CryptoPP::BlockTransformation::BlockTransformation(void)" (??0BlockTransformation@CryptoPP@@QEAA@XZ)

main.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __cdecl CryptoPP::SimpleKeyingInterface::SetKey(unsigned char const *,unsigned __int64,class CryptoPP::NameValuePairs const &)" (?SetKey@SimpleKeyingInterface@CryptoPP@@UEAAXPEBE_KAEBVNameValuePairs@2@@Z)

main.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __cdecl CryptoPP::SimpleKeyingInterface::GetNextIV(class CryptoPP::RandomNumberGenerator &,unsigned char *)" (?GetNextIV@SimpleKeyingInterface@CryptoPP@@UEAAXAEAVRandomNumberGenerator@2@PEAE@Z)

main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: unsigned __int64 __cdecl CryptoPP::SimpleKeyingInterface::ThrowIfInvalidIVLength(int)" (?ThrowIfInvalidIVLength@SimpleKeyingInterface@CryptoPP@@IEAA_KH@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual void __cdecl CryptoPP::BlockOrientedCipherModeBase::Resynchronize(unsigned char const *,int)" (?Resynchronize@BlockOrientedCipherModeBase@CryptoPP@@UEAAXPEBEH@Z)

main.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual unsigned int __cdecl CryptoPP::BlockTransformation::OptimalDataAlignment(void)const " (?OptimalDataAlignment@BlockTransformation@CryptoPP@@UEBAIXZ)

main.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __cdecl CryptoPP::StreamTransformation::ProcessLastBlock(unsigned char *,unsigned char const *,unsigned __int64)" (?ProcessLastBlock@StreamTransformation@CryptoPP@@UEAAXPEAEPEBE_K@Z)

main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void * __cdecl CryptoPP::AlignedAllocate(unsigned __int64)" (?AlignedAllocate@CryptoPP@@YAPEAX_K@Z) referenced in function "public: unsigned char * __cdecl CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<unsigned char,1>::allocate(unsigned __int64,void const *)" (?allocate@?$AllocatorWithCleanup@E$00@CryptoPP@@QEAAPEAE_KPEBX@Z)

main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl CryptoPP::AlignedDeallocate(void *)" (?AlignedDeallocate@CryptoPP@@YAXPEAX@Z) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<unsigned char,1>::deallocate(void *,unsigned __int64)" (?deallocate@?$AllocatorWithCleanup@E$00@CryptoPP@@QEAAXPEAX_K@Z)

main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void * __cdecl CryptoPP::UnalignedAllocate(unsigned __int64)" (?UnalignedAllocate@CryptoPP@@YAPEAX_K@Z) referenced in function "public: unsigned char * __cdecl CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<unsigned char,1>::allocate(unsigned __int64,void const *)" (?allocate@?$AllocatorWithCleanup@E$00@CryptoPP@@QEAAPEAE_KPEBX@Z)

main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl CryptoPP::UnalignedDeallocate(void *)" (?UnalignedDeallocate@CryptoPP@@YAXPEAX@Z) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<unsigned char,1>::deallocate(void *,unsigned __int64)" (?deallocate@?$AllocatorWithCleanup@E$00@CryptoPP@@QEAAXPEAX_K@Z)

main.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __cdecl CryptoPP::BlockOrientedCipherModeBase::UncheckedSetKey(unsigned char const *,unsigned int,class CryptoPP::NameValuePairs const &)" (?UncheckedSetKey@BlockOrientedCipherModeBase@CryptoPP@@UEAAXPEBEIAEBVNameValuePairs@2@@Z)

main.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __cdecl CryptoPP::CBC_Encryption::ProcessData(unsigned char *,unsigned char const *,unsigned __int64)" (?ProcessData@CBC_Encryption@CryptoPP@@UEAAXPEAEPEBE_K@Z)

main.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __cdecl CryptoPP::Rijndael::Base::UncheckedSetKey(unsigned char const *,unsigned int,class CryptoPP::NameValuePairs const &)" (?UncheckedSetKey@Base@Rijndael@CryptoPP@@UEAAXPEBEIAEBVNameValuePairs@3@@Z)

main.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __cdecl CryptoPP::Rijndael::Enc::ProcessAndXorBlock(unsigned char const *,unsigned char const *,unsigned char *)const " (?ProcessAndXorBlock@Enc@Rijndael@CryptoPP@@UEBAXPEBE0PEAE@Z)

main.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual unsigned __int64 __cdecl CryptoPP::Rijndael::Enc::AdvancedProcessBlocks(unsigned char const *,unsigned char const *,unsigned char *,unsigned __int64,unsigned int)const " (?AdvancedProcessBlocks@Enc@Rijndael@CryptoPP@@UEBA_KPEBE0PEAE_KI@Z)
```

I'm using downloaded Qt, and in about section of Qt Creator it says it's compiled with MSVC 2010 32bit.

Comment: Can you add the exact linker errors, please? And did you compile QT from scratch, or is it just the downloaded version? If the latter applies, which compiler had been used for compiling QT?

Comment: I've added the exact errors

Comment: I think the problem here is that you compiled the library with MSVC2013, but the libraries in QT are compiled with MSVC2010, therefore they are incompatible. You must either download MSVC2010 and use it for compilation, or compile QT on your own.

Comment: I thought that only the compiler set up in Qt mattered. Oh well, I guess I'll try with MSVC2010. Thanks.

Comment: @mdm: The same problem arises with qwt, therefore I think it is the fault of the compiler.

Comment: perhaps symbols are not exported? Windows requires these classes to be explicitly exported to be available. Use dependency walker to check

Comment: Dynamic linking involves linking to a dll, and then using something like `QLibrary` to load the dll at runtime. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlibrary.html#details

Comment: Forgive my ignorance with respect to Qt and its IDE... Are you working on a 64-bit platform? If so, how do you specify libs for win64?

Comment: By any chance, are you using Qt and Crypto++ headers in one file? Is it possible that you include qt includes before crypto++? Qt has an unfortunate tendency of defining generic-worded macros that expand into qt-only things (e.g., foreach, which Qt by default expands to `Q_FOREACH` and then happily breaks boost code) and that sometimes collide with symbols defined in other libraries. Often, just reordering includes to make sure all non-qt headers are included /before/ any qt includes solves the problem.

Comment: @martin_pr: you seem to have not heard about disabling "keys" with qmake for those issues.

Comment: @lpapp: you seem to have never seen a mixed codebase large enough that changing compilation flags is not an option.

Comment: @martin_pr: correct, that looks like a very bad idea where components are mixed with other things and cannot have their own properties. We avoid those at all cost. Either way, even in that case, you can disable it very easily as it is a Qt define. It is unlikely that someone has defined exactly the same qt define, so I am sorry, but I do not follow. Please give a _concrete_ example where it is not possible in the real world.

Comment: jww: Yes I'm working on a 64bit platform, and this is the first time I've tried adding an external library so I have no idea.
phyatt: Above example is with the static linking.
martin_pr: I've tried rearranging includes and no luck.

Comment: @lpapp: A very simple example is already stated above - a combination of `boost::foreach` with Qt includes (qglobal.h) and default compilation flags causes the `foreach` to be expanded to `Q_FOREACH`, breaking any boost foreach code. Same can be said about `signals`, `slots` (expanded to `protected` and nothing respectively) and several others (all very generic keywords that are used with other meaning in other projects). Changing the Qt defines globally is a high-impact change, while reordering includes in a single file is not.

Comment: @martin_pr: you clearly do not understand how to disable Qt keywords. Please read about `QT_NO_KEYWORDS` before continuing this discussion. That feature was added ages ago, even the dinosaurs could use it. You are welcome. ;-)

Comment: @lpapp: would you mind being more specific about what exactly, according to you, I do not understand about `QT_NO_KEYWORDS` define? If defined, user code has to use `Q_SIGNALS` and similar. If not defined, it can use `signals` keyword directly. If any user code uses something like `my_code::signals::hello_world`, the `signals` keyword is replaced by `protected`, breaking compilation or, more often, linking. If not defined, any user headers using `signals:` notation break. Is there a mechanism in Qt to allow both? And please tone down your aggressive language.

Comment: @martin_pr You can do it by using either `QT_NO_KEYWORDS` or manually `#undef`ing the colliding symbols before using them for non-Qt purposes. Once you're done, you can `#define` Qt's stuff once again. By the way, it seems that this topic is unrelated to the current question. Maybe open another question about this. :)

Comment: @Venemo: yup, you're right, it went quite far astray. My original point was that the default qt defines sometimes break linking, especially with header-only and mixed libraries, and reordering is a simple poor-man's solution to the problem, thats all :)

Comment: @martin_pr Yes, it might be the case, but we won't know until the OP tells us what's up. :)

Comment: Qt headers never break themselves as they use the proper forms. You are still confused. What is a "poor man solution" should not even needed. Even if someone nonsensically uses Qt keywords in their projects, that has to be fixed, not the issue left in and "solved" by another silly idea. You are suggesting things that the Qt Project suggests again.

Comment: Reordering includes didn't help, so I gave up and just used .net cryptography with c++/cli. I might get back to it when I have more time. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Possibly related: [Linker errors when building DLL dependent on static lib Crypto++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27546541/608639). Its a recent Qt question/answer too.