# Linker errors when building DLL dependent on static lib Crypto++

Tags: c++, qt, qmake, unresolved-external, crypto++

Here is a preface - I have a C++ + Qt application, it consists of several projects and we are using MSVC 2012 to build it. Now, I'm implementing build scripts to start deploying build server. So, I started creating Qt .pro files for each and every project we have.

**Now the problem** - we use Crypto++ library(http://www.cryptopp.com/) which we build from source code and the output is static lib, and we have DLL which depends on cryptlib.lib.

I wrote .pro file for Cryptlib and I'm able to build it using qmake/jom

```
QT           -= core gui
QMAKE_CFLAGS += /Zc:wchar_t

TEMPLATE = lib
TARGET   = cryptlib

Release:DESTDIR = ./Release
Debug:DESTDIR   = ./Debug

CONFIG  += staticlib precompile_header
DEFINES += _USING_V110_SDK71_ WINVER=0x0501 WIN32 _WINDOWS _MBCS
DEFINES -= UNICODE

PRECOMPILED_HEADER = pch.h
DEPENDPATH += .

include(CryptoPP.pri)@
```

I wrote .pro file for my DLL - it compiles fine, *but I'm getting linker errors on linkage phase*. The most interesting thing is that when I build cryptlib with MSVC2012 and *then* build DLL with qmake - then it link OK.

What could be wrong? I checked all proj settings in MSVC projects and applied in my pro files. I checked names mangling in both libs built with MSVC and QT - mangled names look the same. Now I got stuck

```
@# ----------------------------------------------------
# This file is generated by the Qt Visual Studio Add-in.
# ------------------------------------------------------

QT           -= gui core
QMAKE_CFLAGS += /Zc:wchar_t

TEMPLATE = lib
TARGET   = PSGLicensing

Release:DESTDIR = ./Release
Debug:DESTDIR   = ./Debug

CONFIG  += dll
DEFINES += _AFXDLL _USING_V110_SDK71_ WIN32 _WINDOWS _WINDLL _USRDLL DLL_LIBRARY PSGLICENSING_DLL_BUILD _MBCS _VC80_UPGRADE=0x0710
DEFINES -= UNICODE

PRECOMPILED_HEADER = stdafx.h
DEPENDPATH += .

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/../CryptoPP/Release/ -lcryptlib
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/../CryptoPP/Debug/ -lcryptlib

INCLUDEPATH += $$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/../CryptoPP/
DEPENDPATH += $$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/../CryptoPP/

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/../CryptoPP/Release/cryptlib.lib
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/../CryptoPP/Debug/cryptlib.lib

include(PSGLicensing.pri)@
```

In MSVC2012 we have following settings for

**CryptLib**

```
*Compiler:* /Yu"pch.h" /GS /GL /analyze- /W3 /Gy- /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /Ob2 /Fd"Release\vc110.pdb" /fp:precise /Zp1 /D "_USING_V110_SDK71_" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "USE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS" /D "WIN32" /D "WINVER=0x0501" /D "_VC80_UPGRADE=0x0710" /errorReport:prompt /GF- /WX- /Zc:forScope /arch:SSE /Gd /Oy /Oi /MD /Fa"Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Release\" /Fp"Release\cryptlib.pch" 

*Linker:* /OUT:"SecretPath\CryptoPP\Release\cryptlib.lib" /LTCG /NOLOGO
```

and here are settings for **DLL**

```
*Compiler*: /Yu"stdafx.h" /GS /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /I"SecretPath\PSGLicensing\IncludeExp" /Zi /Gm- /O2 /Fd"Release\vc110.pdb" /fp:precise /D "_USING_V110_SDK71_" /D "WIN32" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_USRDLL" /D "PSGLICENSING_DLL_BUILD" /D "_VC80_UPGRADE=0x0710" /D "_WINDLL" /D "_MBCS" /D "_AFXDLL" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oy- /MD /Fa"Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Release\" /Fp"Release\PSGLicensing.pch" 

*Linker:* /OUT:"SecretPah\PSGLicensing\Release\PSGLicensing.dll" /MANIFEST /PDB:"SecretPath\PSGLicensing\Release\PSGLicensing.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE:NO "..\CryptoPP\Release\cryptlib.lib" "SecretPath\CryptoPP\Release\cryptlib.lib" /DEF:".\PSGLicensing.def" /IMPLIB:"SecretPath\PSGLicensing\Release\PSGLicensing.lib" /DEBUG /DLL /MACHINE:X86 /OPT:REF /SAFESEH /INCREMENTAL:NO /PGD:"SecretPath\PSGLicensing\Release\PSGLicensing.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS",5.01" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"Release\PSGLicensing.dll.intermediate.manifest" /OPT:ICF /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /TLBID:1
```

Here is jom output

```
@   C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Release
    link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /INCREMENTAL:NO /DLL /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:Release\PSGLicensing.dll.embed.manifest /OUT:Release\PSGLicensing.dll @C:\Users\ANDRIY~1.GLO\AppData\Local\Temp\PSGLicensing.dll.6212.16.jom
   Creating library Release\PSGLicensing.lib and object Release\PSGLicensing.exp
GenerateRandomBlock.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall CryptoPP::CFB_CipherTemplate<class CryptoPP::AbstractPolicyHolder<class CryptoPP::CFB_CipherAbstractPolicy,class CryptoPP::CFB_ModePolicy> >::ProcessData(unsigned char *,unsigned char const *,unsigned int)" (?ProcessData@?$CFB_CipherTemplate@V?$AbstractPolicyHolder@VCFB_CipherAbstractPolicy@CryptoPP@@VCFB_ModePolicy@2@@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@UAEXPAEPBEI@Z)
GenerateRandomBlock.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall CryptoPP::CFB_CipherTemplate<class CryptoPP::AbstractPolicyHolder<class CryptoPP::CFB_CipherAbstractPolicy,class CryptoPP::CFB_ModePolicy> >::Resynchronize(unsigned char const *,int)" (?Resynchronize@?$CFB_CipherTemplate@V?$AbstractPolicyHolder@VCFB_CipherAbstractPolicy@CryptoPP@@VCFB_ModePolicy@2@@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@UAEXPBEH@Z)
GenerateRandomBlock.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall CryptoPP::CFB_CipherTemplate<class CryptoPP::AbstractPolicyHolder<class CryptoPP::CFB_CipherAbstractPolicy,class CryptoPP::CFB_ModePolicy> >::UncheckedSetKey(unsigned char const *,unsigned int,class CryptoPP::NameValuePairs const &)" (?UncheckedSetKey@?$CFB_CipherTemplate@V?$AbstractPolicyHolder@VCFB_CipherAbstractPolicy@CryptoPP@@VCFB_ModePolicy@2@@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@MAEXPBEIABVNameValuePairs@2@@Z)
GenerateRandomBlock.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: virtual void __thiscall CryptoPP::CFB_EncryptionTemplate<class CryptoPP::AbstractPolicyHolder<class CryptoPP::CFB_CipherAbstractPolicy,class CryptoPP::CFB_ModePolicy> >::CombineMessageAndShiftRegister(unsigned char *,unsigned char *,unsigned char const *,unsigned int)" (?CombineMessageAndShiftRegister@?$CFB_EncryptionTemplate@V?$AbstractPolicyHolder@VCFB_CipherAbstractPolicy@CryptoPP@@VCFB_ModePolicy@2@@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@EAEXPAE0PBEI@Z)
cryptlib.lib(rsa.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall CryptoPP::IteratedHashBase<unsigned int,class CryptoPP::HashTransformation>::Update(unsigned char const *,unsigned int)" (?Update@?$IteratedHashBase@IVHashTransformation@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@UAEXPBEI@Z)
LicensingEx.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall CryptoPP::IteratedHashBase<unsigned int,class CryptoPP::HashTransformation>::Update(unsigned char const *,unsigned int)" (?Update@?$IteratedHashBase@IVHashTransformation@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@UAEXPBEI@Z)
cryptlib.lib(randpool.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall CryptoPP::IteratedHashBase<unsigned int,class CryptoPP::HashTransformation>::Update(unsigned char const *,unsigned int)" (?Update@?$IteratedHashBase@IVHashTransformation@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@UAEXPBEI@Z)
cryptlib.lib(md5.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall CryptoPP::IteratedHashBase<unsigned int,class CryptoPP::HashTransformation>::Update(unsigned char const *,unsigned int)" (?Update@?$IteratedHashBase@IVHashTransformation@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@UAEXPBEI@Z)
cryptlib.lib(integer.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall CryptoPP::IteratedHashBase<unsigned int,class CryptoPP::HashTransformation>::Update(unsigned char const *,unsigned int)" (?Update@?$IteratedHashBase@IVHashTransformation@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@UAEXPBEI@Z)
cryptlib.lib(rsa.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual unsigned char * __thiscall CryptoPP::IteratedHashBase<unsigned int,class CryptoPP::HashTransformation>::CreateUpdateSpace(unsigned int &)" (?CreateUpdateSpace@?$IteratedHashBase@IVHashTransformation@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@UAEPAEAAI@Z)
LicensingEx.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual unsigned char * __thiscall CryptoPP::IteratedHashBase<unsigned int,class CryptoPP::HashTransformation>::CreateUpdateSpace(unsigned int &)" (?CreateUpdateSpace@?$IteratedHashBase@IVHashTransformation@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@UAEPAEAAI@Z)
cryptlib.lib(randpool.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual unsigned char * __thiscall CryptoPP::IteratedHashBase<unsigned int,class CryptoPP::HashTransformation>::CreateUpdateSpace(unsigned int &)" (?CreateUpdateSpace@?$IteratedHashBase@IVHashTransformation@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@UAEPAEAAI@Z)
cryptlib.lib(md5.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual unsigned char * __thiscall CryptoPP::IteratedHashBase<unsigned int,class CryptoPP::HashTransformation>::CreateUpdateSpace(unsigned int &)" (?CreateUpdateSpace@?$IteratedHashBase@IVHashTransformation@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@UAEPAEAAI@Z)
cryptlib.lib(integer.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual unsigned char * __thiscall CryptoPP::IteratedHashBase<unsigned int,class CryptoPP::HashTransformation>::CreateUpdateSpace(unsigned int &)" (?CreateUpdateSpace@?$IteratedHashBase@IVHashTransformation@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@UAEPAEAAI@Z)
cryptlib.lib(rsa.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall CryptoPP::IteratedHashBase<unsigned int,class CryptoPP::HashTransformation>::Restart(void)" (?Restart@?$IteratedHashBase@IVHashTransformation@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@UAEXXZ)
LicensingEx.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall CryptoPP::IteratedHashBase<unsigned int,class CryptoPP::HashTransformation>::Restart(void)" (?Restart@?$IteratedHashBase@IVHashTransformation@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@UAEXXZ)
cryptlib.lib(randpool.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall CryptoPP::IteratedHashBase<unsigned int,class CryptoPP::HashTransformation>::Restart(void)" (?Restart@?$IteratedHashBase@IVHashTransformation@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@UAEXXZ)
cryptlib.lib(md5.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall CryptoPP::IteratedHashBase<unsigned int,class CryptoPP::HashTransformation>::Restart(void)" (?Restart@?$IteratedHashBase@IVHashTransformation@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@UAEXXZ)
cryptlib.lib(integer.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall CryptoPP::IteratedHashBase<unsigned int,class CryptoPP::HashTransformation>::Restart(void)" (?Restart@?$IteratedHashBase@IVHashTransformation@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@UAEXXZ)
cryptlib.lib(rsa.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall CryptoPP::IteratedHashBase<unsigned int,class CryptoPP::HashTransformation>::TruncatedFinal(unsigned char *,unsigned int)" (?TruncatedFinal@?$IteratedHashBase@IVHashTransformation@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@UAEXPAEI@Z)
LicensingEx.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall CryptoPP::IteratedHashBase<unsigned int,class CryptoPP::HashTransformation>::TruncatedFinal(unsigned char *,unsigned int)" (?TruncatedFinal@?$IteratedHashBase@IVHashTransformation@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@UAEXPAEI@Z)
cryptlib.lib(randpool.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall CryptoPP::IteratedHashBase<unsigned int,class CryptoPP::HashTransformation>::TruncatedFinal(unsigned char *,unsigned int)" (?TruncatedFinal@?$IteratedHashBase@IVHashTransformation@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@UAEXPAEI@Z)
cryptlib.lib(md5.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall CryptoPP::IteratedHashBase<unsigned int,class CryptoPP::HashTransformation>::TruncatedFinal(unsigned char *,unsigned int)" (?TruncatedFinal@?$IteratedHashBase@IVHashTransformation@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@UAEXPAEI@Z)
cryptlib.lib(integer.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall CryptoPP::IteratedHashBase<unsigned int,class CryptoPP::HashTransformation>::TruncatedFinal(unsigned char *,unsigned int)" (?TruncatedFinal@?$IteratedHashBase@IVHashTransformation@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@UAEXPAEI@Z)
LicensingEx.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual unsigned int __thiscall CryptoPP::IteratedHashBase<unsigned int,class CryptoPP::HashTransformation>::HashMultipleBlocks(unsigned int const *,unsigned int)" (?HashMultipleBlocks@?$IteratedHashBase@IVHashTransformation@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@MAEIPBII@Z)
cryptlib.lib(md5.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual unsigned int __thiscall CryptoPP::IteratedHashBase<unsigned int,class CryptoPP::HashTransformation>::HashMultipleBlocks(unsigned int const *,unsigned int)" (?HashMultipleBlocks@?$IteratedHashBase@IVHashTransformation@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@MAEIPBII@Z)
cryptlib.lib(integer.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual unsigned int __thiscall CryptoPP::IteratedHashBase<unsigned int,class CryptoPP::HashTransformation>::HashMultipleBlocks(unsigned int const *,unsigned int)" (?HashMultipleBlocks@?$IteratedHashBase@IVHashTransformation@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@MAEIPBII@Z)
cryptlib.lib(rsa.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual unsigned int __thiscall CryptoPP::IteratedHashBase<unsigned int,class CryptoPP::HashTransformation>::HashMultipleBlocks(unsigned int const *,unsigned int)" (?HashMultipleBlocks@?$IteratedHashBase@IVHashTransformation@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@MAEIPBII@Z)
cryptlib.lib(integer.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class CryptoPP::Integer __thiscall CryptoPP::AbstractGroup<class CryptoPP::Integer>::ScalarMultiply(class CryptoPP::Integer const &,class CryptoPP::Integer const &)const " (?ScalarMultiply@?$AbstractGroup@VInteger@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@UBE?AVInteger@2@ABV32@0@Z)
cryptlib.lib(rsa.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class CryptoPP::Integer __thiscall CryptoPP::AbstractGroup<class CryptoPP::Integer>::ScalarMultiply(class CryptoPP::Integer const &,class CryptoPP::Integer const &)const " (?ScalarMultiply@?$AbstractGroup@VInteger@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@UBE?AVInteger@2@ABV32@0@Z)
cryptlib.lib(integer.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class CryptoPP::Integer __thiscall CryptoPP::AbstractGroup<class CryptoPP::Integer>::CascadeScalarMultiply(class CryptoPP::Integer const &,class CryptoPP::Integer const &,class CryptoPP::Integer const &,class CryptoPP::Integer const &)const " (?CascadeScalarMultiply@?$AbstractGroup@VInteger@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@UBE?AVInteger@2@ABV32@000@Z)
cryptlib.lib(rsa.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class CryptoPP::Integer __thiscall CryptoPP::AbstractGroup<class CryptoPP::Integer>::CascadeScalarMultiply(class CryptoPP::Integer const &,class CryptoPP::Integer const &,class CryptoPP::Integer const &,class CryptoPP::Integer const &)const " (?CascadeScalarMultiply@?$AbstractGroup@VInteger@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@UBE?AVInteger@2@ABV32@000@Z) referenced in function "public: class CryptoPP::GetValueHelperClass<class CryptoPP::InvertibleRSAFunction,class CryptoPP::RSAFunction> & __thiscall CryptoPP::GetValueHelperClass<class CryptoPP::InvertibleRSAFunction,class CryptoPP::RSAFunction>::operator()<class CryptoPP::Integer>(char const *,class CryptoPP::Integer const & (__thiscall CryptoPP::InvertibleRSAFunction::*)(void)const )" (??$?RVInteger@CryptoPP@@@?$GetValueHelperClass@VInvertibleRSAFunction@CryptoPP@@VRSAFunction@2@@CryptoPP@@QAEAAV01@PBDP8InvertibleRSAFunction@1@BEABVInteger@1@XZ@Z)
cryptlib.lib(integer.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall CryptoPP::AbstractGroup<class CryptoPP::Integer>::SimultaneousMultiply(class CryptoPP::Integer *,class CryptoPP::Integer const &,class CryptoPP::Integer const *,unsigned int)const " (?SimultaneousMultiply@?$AbstractGroup@VInteger@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@UBEXPAVInteger@2@ABV32@PBV32@I@Z)
cryptlib.lib(rsa.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall CryptoPP::AbstractGroup<class CryptoPP::Integer>::SimultaneousMultiply(class CryptoPP::Integer *,class CryptoPP::Integer const &,class CryptoPP::Integer const *,unsigned int)const " (?SimultaneousMultiply@?$AbstractGroup@VInteger@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@UBEXPAVInteger@2@ABV32@PBV32@I@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall CryptoPP::InvertibleRSAFunction::Initialize(class CryptoPP::Integer const &,class CryptoPP::Integer const &,class CryptoPP::Integer const &)" (?Initialize@InvertibleRSAFunction@CryptoPP@@QAEXABVInteger@2@00@Z)
cryptlib.lib(integer.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class CryptoPP::Integer __thiscall CryptoPP::AbstractRing<class CryptoPP::Integer>::Exponentiate(class CryptoPP::Integer const &,class CryptoPP::Integer const &)const " (?Exponentiate@?$AbstractRing@VInteger@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@UBE?AVInteger@2@ABV32@0@Z) referenced in function "class CryptoPP::Integer __cdecl CryptoPP::a_exp_b_mod_c(class CryptoPP::Integer const &,class CryptoPP::Integer const &,class CryptoPP::Integer const &)" (?a_exp_b_mod_c@CryptoPP@@YA?AVInteger@1@ABV21@00@Z)
cryptlib.lib(rsa.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class CryptoPP::Integer __thiscall CryptoPP::AbstractRing<class CryptoPP::Integer>::Exponentiate(class CryptoPP::Integer const &,class CryptoPP::Integer const &)const " (?Exponentiate@?$AbstractRing@VInteger@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@UBE?AVInteger@2@ABV32@0@Z)
cryptlib.lib(integer.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class CryptoPP::Integer __thiscall CryptoPP::AbstractRing<class CryptoPP::Integer>::CascadeExponentiate(class CryptoPP::Integer const &,class CryptoPP::Integer const &,class CryptoPP::Integer const &,class CryptoPP::Integer const &)const " (?CascadeExponentiate@?$AbstractRing@VInteger@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@UBE?AVInteger@2@ABV32@000@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual class CryptoPP::Integer __thiscall CryptoPP::ModularArithmetic::CascadeExponentiate(class CryptoPP::Integer const &,class CryptoPP::Integer const &,class CryptoPP::Integer const &,class CryptoPP::Integer const &)const " (?CascadeExponentiate@ModularArithmetic@CryptoPP@@UBE?AVInteger@2@ABV32@000@Z)
cryptlib.lib(integer.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall CryptoPP::AbstractRing<class CryptoPP::Integer>::SimultaneousExponentiate(class CryptoPP::Integer *,class CryptoPP::Integer const &,class CryptoPP::Integer const *,unsigned int)const " (?SimultaneousExponentiate@?$AbstractRing@VInteger@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@UBEXPAVInteger@2@ABV32@PBV32@I@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall CryptoPP::ModularArithmetic::SimultaneousExponentiate(class CryptoPP::Integer *,class CryptoPP::Integer const &,class CryptoPP::Integer const *,unsigned int)const " (?SimultaneousExponentiate@ModularArithmetic@CryptoPP@@UBEXPAVInteger@2@ABV32@PBV32@I@Z)
cryptlib.lib(integer.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class CryptoPP::Integer const & __thiscall CryptoPP::AbstractEuclideanDomain<class CryptoPP::Integer>::Gcd(class CryptoPP::Integer const &,class CryptoPP::Integer const &)const " (?Gcd@?$AbstractEuclideanDomain@VInteger@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@UBEABVInteger@2@ABV32@0@Z)
Release\PSGLicensing.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 16 unresolved externals
@
```

Comment: This is not a solution to your problem, but I highly recommend switching to CMake. It just makes life a lot easier.

Comment: First, qmake will not compile/link. It will create Makefiles. The link command does not get a library passed. Therefor it will not find the required symbols. I am not seeing a ``LIBS += ...`` in your generated profile, may you will have to add the crypto-library to the required libraries in the msv-studio?

Comment: @juzzlin Easier is a very subjective point of view. If your whole infrastructure is built around qmake and traditional setup, using cmake is a lot of work. It also requires to read into cmake. I prefer the traditional setup currently and I am always upset if i get forced to install cmake...

Comment: @SebastianLange LIBS section is present in DLL .pro file. Moreover, when I build cryptlib with MSVC, DLL links fine with that lib (output dir is the same both for MSVC and Qt builds)

Comment: @Andriy my bad. Did not check the second pro file. Nevertheless the link command still misses the path to the library. Not sure why this happens though.

Comment: You probably could add: ``LIBS+=quote($$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/../CryptoPP/Release/libcryptlib.lib)`` to enforce the use of libcryptlib.lib file and not looking for .dll.

Comment: @SebastianLange   it didn't help LIBS+=quote($$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/../CryptoPP/Release/libcryptlib.lib)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the version of .pro file for CryptLib with which built library is linkable.

```
QT           -= core gui
QMAKE_CFLAGS += /Zc:wchar_t /GL

TEMPLATE = lib
TARGET   = cryptlib

Release:DESTDIR = ./Release
Debug:DESTDIR   = ./Debug

CONFIG  += staticlib
DEFINES += _USING_V110_SDK71_ WINVER=0x0501 WIN32 _WINDOWS _MBCS USE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS
DEFINES -= UNICODE

DEPENDPATH += .

include(CryptoPP.pri)
```

So, all I did is added **USE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS** to DEFINES and removed **PRECOMPILED_HEADER_FILE = pch.h**. I do not know how it actually helped, but it helped.